# How to peek on channels without blocking and still being able to detect hangup?

Tags: rust, nonblocking, channel, peek

According to the doc of [.try_iter()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_iter) method of the `Receiver` end of a Rust `std::mpsc::channel`, I understand that this iterator either yield "None":

- when there is no data in the channel
- or when the other end of the channel has hung up.

In my case, I would like to [`peek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.peek) into the channel, without blocking, so as to determinate whether:

- there is data (but *without* consuming it), or
- there is no data, or
- the channel has hung up.

The problem is that if I..

```rust
match my_receiver.try_iter().peekable().peek() {
    Some(data) => {/* there is data */}
    None => {/* there is no data, but there may be later.. or maybe not, because the channel has maybe hung up, I can't tell! */}
}
```

.. there are only two cases I can discriminate.

How can I peek into the `receiver` end of a channel and discriminate between those three possible outcomes without blocking or consuming the data when there is some?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `try_iter()` method returns an iterator that discards the `Error` values, so you cannot differentiate between the cases.

You could create your own iterator which iterates over the `Result` rather than discarding error values:

```
pub struct TryIterResult<'a, T: 'a> {
    rx: &'a Receiver<T>,
}

pub fn try_iter_result<'a, T>(rx: &'a Receiver<T>) -> TryIterResult<'a, T> {
    TryIterResult { rx: &rx }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for TryIterResult<'a, T> {
    type Item = Result<T, TryRecvError>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Result<T, TryRecvError>> {
        match self.rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(data) => Some(Ok(data)),
            Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => Some(Err(TryRecvError::Empty)),
            Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => None
        }
    }
}
```

You would then be able to get a peekable iterator which would return three possible conditions:

```
match try_iter_result(my_receiver).peekable().peek() {
    Some(Ok(data)) =>{ /* there is data */},
    Some(Err(_)) => { /* nothing available right now */ },
    None => {/* disconnected */}
}
```

Comment: You don't need the nested `match`: your top-level one can match directly on `Some (Ok (data))` and `Some (Err (_))` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=398418924821ee4921958693a21a7168)).

Comment: This does work. Thank you :) Do you think there is any chance to have this integrated to the standard library?

Comment: Thanks @Jmb. I originally had it that way but got the syntax slightly wrong (see edits if you are interested).

Comment: @iago-lito I doubt they would make a non backward compatible change like this. You could always propose it though!

Answer (score -2):

You can use [try_recv](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_recv) to do what you want.

It returns a `Result<T, TryRecvError>` and `TryRecvError` can be either `Empty` or `Disconnected`.

```rust
match my_receiver.try_recv() {
    Ok(data) => {/* handle data */}
    Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => {/* handle sender disconnected */}
    Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {/* handle no data available yet */}
}
```

Comment: `try_recv` will consume the data. OP wants a solution where the data is not consumed.